# Adding a custom area for blocks in a custom layout

Tags: template, layout, cms

Ok, So I've made a module and use it to manage all the custom layouts on my store. Now I need to just add some blocks to certain pages using the template. I added the following line to my custom layout:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_left') ?>
```

And inside the Update Layout XML I added the following:

```
<reference name="cms_left">
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_left_test" before="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cms_left_test</block_id></action>
    </block>    
</reference>
```

And encase its relevent here is part the relevant part of my moudles config.xml that handles this custom layout:

```
<cms_pages module="page" translate="label">
    <label>cms pages</label>
    <template>page/cms_pages.phtml</template>
    <layout_handle>cms pages</layout_handle>
</cms_pages>
```

From what I know this should now display the cms_left_test block on this page, however it;s not working. Have I missed out a step somewhere? I tried looking up some examples, but because I'm drawing bits and pieces from all over I'm not sure if my approach is totally correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the block 'cms_left' defined in your layout? Or better yet ''IS IT defined?'.
You are calling this:

```
<reference name="cms_left">
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_left_test" before="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cms_left_test</block_id></action>
    </block>    
</reference>
```

But in order to be able to reference a block, the block should exist.

I think you are missing this piece of xml in your custom layout file.

```
<default>    
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="cms_left" as="cms_left" translate="label">
            <label>CMS left block</label>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 2):

From what it looks like, the block `cms_left` is not defined anywhere. In order for it to work, you should define it as `core/text_list` somewhere in your layout definitions. Then you can reference it and add new blocks to it, like you are trying to do. Assuming `cms_left` is a direct child of `root`, you can do the following:

```
<reference name="root">
    <block name="cms_left" type="core/text_list" />
</reference>
```

Make sure you add this before your code above.